# Unable to connect to SQLServer Kafka Connect

Tags: sql-server, docker, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a docker image as located here
https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev which has all the good stuff that I am using for development. I've tried to add a JDBC connector to push into a Kafka topic however am getting this error. I've made a consumer in Java which is working fine however I would like to use KafkaConnect

`Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://servername for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://servername`

```
name=JdbcSourceConnector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.user=user
connection.password=password
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://servername
topic.prefix=test
table.whitelist=dbo.IB_WEBLOG_DUMMY_small
query=SELECT * FROM IB_WEBLOG_DUMMY_small
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
poll.interval.ms=5000
table.poll.interval.ms=120000
mode=bulk
```

What should I be looking into to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JDBC driver’s JAR file is not in Kafka Connect’s classpath. Put it there and you will be [good to go](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html):

> One option is to install the JDBC driver jar alongside the connector. The packaged connector is installed in the `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` directory, relative to the installation directory. If you have installed from Debian or RPM packages, the connector will be installed in `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`. If you installed from zip or tar files, the connector will be installed in the path given above under the directory where you unzipped the Confluent Platform archive.
>
> Alternatively, you can set the CLASSPATH variable before running connect-standalone or connect-distributed. For example:
>
> `$ CLASSPATH=/usr/local/firebird/* ./bin/connect-distributed ./config/connect-distributed.properties`

Alternatively, put all the SQL Server JDBC JAR files in the `libs` dir under the root folder of Apache Kafka. But that would pollute the classpath and is better to be avoided in production.

Comment: I don't have the director /usr/share/java. Is this something to do with the docker image that I am using?

Comment: Put your JAR file anywhere you like, for example `/my/jars/`. Then if you are using `bash`, run `EXPORT CLASSPATH=/my/jars/*`. Then run `./bin/connect-distributed ./config/connect-distributed.properties`.